# Inserting zero rows takes 2 minutes

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I have a long select statement finished with insert, the select returns zero rows in few seconds but insert part takes 1 to 2 minutes....

```
 with t1 as ()

insert into myscheme.sometable -- if I comment this line it will return zero rows in 3 sec

select t1
```

To simplify even more, this code is 3 seconds and result is zero rows:

```
 with t1 as ()

select t1
```

and below is 2 minutes however it is using select statement running 3 sec.(also for zero rows to insert):

```
 with t1 as ()
insert into myscheme.sometable
select t1
```

Comment: Let me guess - main select includes something from `myscheme.sometable`? Can you select needed rows into temporary table and insert from there?

Comment: Correct :) I'm checking if some data already there not to include them in final insert. The select is actually really heavy in some parts so to avoid those calculations I check if some data are already processed. Hoped to go down with calculations time but actually it's worse.

Comment: You need to edit your question, add the actual statements, and `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the slow queries.

Comment: And *as always*, your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

So I've used Arvo suggestion to do trick with tmp table:

```
select needed rows into temporary table and insert from there?
```

Not sure why postgres is doing such antioptimization while doing optimization but the trick with tmp table is good enough!

**To sum up - when inserting into a table that is also used in select query before insert - best it is to create temp table and  do insert from that table.**

Comment: Without the results from EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) you have no idea what is going on and why the query is slow. Making a statement that you need a temp table is just a wild guess and no guarantee that it works tomorrow or next week.